# After app close, return back to same activity

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am creating an android quiz application but the only thing I am struggling on is when the user is on a question and then they close the app, I want them to return back to that same question when they restart the app.

Is there a function I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override onPause and onResume methods of your activity.